# How to make BitmapImage disposable

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, windows-store

I need to use a `BitmapImage` in a `using` statement, how could this be done?

```
using (BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage())
{
    ...
```

I am guessing the way to do it is by extending `IDisposable` but I have never done that before.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's not already IDisposable, then why do you assume it needs to be disposed? And why do you _need_ to use it in a using statement?

Comment: Okay, yes you are right, I'm just adjusting some code and have never used `using` statements before - which I have now dumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. `BitmapImage` is sealed so you can't derive from it. Furthermore, I don't know why you would implement `IDisposable` in a .NET Framework class. The most you could do is a wrapper class which would contain your `BitmapImage`, and implement `IDisposable`.

Example:

```
class DisposableBitmapImageWrapper : IDisposable
{
    public BitmapImage Bitmap { get; private set; }

    public DisposableBitmapImageWrapper(BitmapImage bitmap)
    {
        Bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Do something with the BitmapImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for implementing `IDisposable` is to free unmanaged resources in an object when you no longer need to reference that object. You don't need to wrap the `BitmapImage` and implement `IDisposable` becuase there isn't any unmanaged resources associated with a `BitmapImage`.